# asynchronous loading of javascript files timeout

Tags: javascript, timeout

I'm loading my javascript files asynchronously. I need to ensure that the order of loading is met. Here's my loading function:

```
    function addTag(name, attributes, cond) {
        var el = document.createElement(name),
            attrName;
        for (attrName in attributes) {
          el.setAttribute(attrName, attributes[attrName]);
        }
        if(cond != ''){
            el = document.createComment('[if '+cond+']>'+outerHTML(el) + '<![endif]');
        }
        var headEl = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        headEl.appendChild(el); 
    }

    function outerHTML(node){
        // if IE, Chrome take the internal method otherwise build one
        return node.outerHTML || (
            function(n){
                var div = document.createElement('div'), h;
                div.appendChild(n);
                h = div.innerHTML;
                div = null;
                return h;
            })(node);
    }
```

I was thinking that a timeout function should be called but im not quite sure and also not quite sure about the interval time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use callback functions..So it will execute only after main fuction executes. Also you can use nested callback functions

Comment: @latheefitzmeontv can you please provide a code example?

Comment: `fuction a(d){return d.length}` then main function `function d(b, c){console.log(b);console.log(c(b))}` then call `d("ffff", a)` Here call back function `c` is passed.result is `ffff 4`

Answer (score 0):

```
function callback(arg){
    //your stuffs
}
function main(arg, callback){
    //stuffs
    callback(arg);
}
```

Hope this helps.For [more](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)